# Why doesn't Data.Sequence have `insert' or `insertBy', and how do I efficiently implement them?

Tags: haskell, containers

I was confused by the lack of these functions in the interface for the Sequence type, since Data.List provides these functions. Is there an efficiency problem here, or is it just a lack of demand for these functions?

And since they're not part of Data.Sequence, how can I efficiently implement them for my purposes?

Comment: It's not quite as complete as `Data.List`, but the Sequence interface relies heavily on type classes.  `map` from `Functor`, `fold` from `Foldable`, etc.  You can also use ListLike, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike, which has an instance for the Sequence type and would give you a much more complete interface, including `insert` and `insertBy`; I think the interface is the same as Mikhail's second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
> let insertBy cmp x seq = let (s1,s2) = partition (\y -> cmp x y == GT) seq in (s1 |> x) >< s2
> let s = fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
> insertBy compare 2 s
fromList [1,2,2,3,4,5]
```

Or you can just ape the version for lists:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

module Main
    where

import Data.Sequence

insertBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> a -> Seq a -> Seq a
insertBy _   x (viewl -> EmptyL) = singleton x
insertBy cmp x ys@(viewl -> (y:<ys'))
 = case cmp x y of
     GT -> y <| insertBy cmp x ys'
     _  -> x <| ys
```

Comment: I suppose that would be essentially as fast as the fastest method. I am going to mark this answer as correct, because I just realized I need more than Sequence, I need to enforce the invariant that the sequence is always ordered, so that I can do insertion in O(log n) time instead of O(n) time.

Comment: @danharaj, considered Data.Set?

Comment: @luqui, I have, but my ordering changes during the course of the algorithm I am implenting, Bentley-Ottmann for reference. Since the order relation changes, I can't use Data.Set. The ordering changes in a behaved way, though, so a binary search is the way to go.