# "List" with efficient insert/delete

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a "List" with log(N) insert/delete at index i.  I put the word "List" in quotes, because I don't mean it to be an actual Haskell List, but just any ordered container with a bunch of objects (in fact, it probably needs some sort of tree internally).  I am surprised that I haven't found a great solution yet....

This is the best solution I have so far-  Use Data.Sequence with these two functions.

```
doInsert position value seq = before >< ( value <| after)
     where
     (before, after) = splitAt position seq

doDelete position seq = before >< (drop 1 after)
     where
     (before, after) = splitAt position seq
```

While these are technically all log(N) functions, it feels like I am doing a bunch of extra stuff for each insert/delete....  In other words, this scales like  K*log(N) for a K that is larger than it should be.  Plus, since I have to define this stuff myself, I feel like I am using Sequence for something it wasn't designed for.

Is there a better way?

This is a related question (although it only deals with Sequences, I would happily use anything else): [Why doesn't Data.Sequence have `insert' or `insertBy', and how do I efficiently implement them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417946/why-doesnt-data-sequence-have-insert-or-insertby-and-how-do-i-efficiently)

And yes, this question is related to this other one I posted a few days ago: [Massive number of XML edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603539/massive-number-of-xml-edits)

Comment: why not [:: Data.Map.Map Int a](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html)?

Comment: @WillNess- insert would have to update all `i` for values larger than the insert point, so I don't think this works.

Comment: the standard data structure solution for this IIRC is a tree where nodes also carry the amount of elements to their left. see if http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-tree is relevant.

Comment: @WillNess- I am assuming it will be a tree structure.... I'm looking for something built into Haskell that implements this.  It seems strange to me that I might have to build something so basic by hand.

Comment: @jamshidh If you can't find a suitable implementation on Hackage, then make your own and submit it.  It's likely that if you need it, someone else will too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the objection to `Data.Sequence` is. Can you please spell out what your success criteria are? What would an alternative choice need to demonstrate to be a clear improvement over `Data.Sequence`?

Comment: @DanielWagner- Data.Sequence is acceptable, but it has the problems I mention above (there should be a way to insert/delete without the intermediary ripping apart and rebuilding the whole tree, and the fact that these functions aren't a part of the lib already makes me feel it wasn't written with this purpose in mind).  I am just reaching out to find the Haskell idomatic solution, or verify that this is really the recommended way.  I mean, really, why aren't insert/delete already part of the sequence lib, what am I missing?

Comment: @DanielWagner- Sorry for the split comment, but I wanted to ask, do you not agree that this is less than efficient (breaking a tree into two parts, then rebuilding)?  For all I know, it has to rebalance the whole tree three times when it does this (once for the ripping apart, once for the insert, once for the merge).

Comment: You might want to try a naive implementation using lists and then benchmark and optimize the bottlenecks. Using typeclasses like Functor, Foldable and Traversable will make it easier to swap out data structures.

Comment: I think Data.Sequence serves the purpose. Both operations (split, and append (><) ) are proportional to log(min(n1,n2)) where n1+n2 ~ n here. If the elements are inserted randomly, the overhead K in K*log(n) should be reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

There are structures such as catenable seqs, catenable queues, etc. that can give you O(1) join. However, all such structures I know of get away with this by giving you O(i) split. If you want split and join both to be as optimal as possible, I think a fingertree (aka `Sequence`) is your best bet. The entire point of the way `Sequence` is structured is to ensure that splitting, joining, etc. have an asymptotically not terrible amount of juggling to do when splitting and joining, among other things.

If you *could* get away with an `IntMap` which started sparse and got denser, and was occasionally "rebuilt" when things got too dense, then that *might* give you better performance -- but that really depends on your patterns of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you work carefully with predefined Haskell Lists, there should be no problem with them.
(For example when concatenating two lists).

If you'd like to find an implementation for lists, with efficient insertion and deletion, an AVLTree or any kind or balanced binary tree would work.
For example store in an AVLTree a tuple (Int, a) where Int is the index of the list and a the elem.
Therefore, on average complexity, the operations would be logarithmic for insertion and deletion.

I hope this answers your question.